# I have a file in my local location example desktop and want show file content on Blazor Web assembly UI

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, blazor, blazor-webassembly

```
@using System.IO

<h3>Log File Content</h3>

<RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="fileContent" Multiline="true" ReadOnly="true" Style="min-height: 200px;" />


@code {
private string fileContent;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{       
    
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\sample.txt";

    try
    {
        fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        //using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        //{
        //    fileContent = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle file reading error
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have the location of the Txt file location and want to show the file content on the Blazor Web assembly UI screen.

I tried to read the file using

this

```
 fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

and this

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    fileContent = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

but getting an error that the file is not in the location but the file is there.
I believe it is related to the blazor path issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the file system of the client machine due to browser security restrictions.

You can either ask the user to upload the file, so it can be read at the server side. or if the file is on the server side where the app is hosted, you can make http call and get its content.